# How to prevent Web-Audio on iOS from switching to mono when accessing the microphone?

Tags: ios, mono, web-audio-api, microphone

we are developing a web app, that is supposed to play high quality stereo in combination with accessing the microphone input. We got this to work on all android and pc browsers, but the iphone is refusing to do this properly. We nailed the problem down to the access of the microphone input by "getUserMedia". Web audio plays stereo, until the microphone is enabled. Then, the quality drops and the output goes to mono. I have researched this problem in the internet, but only found posts that are several years old. My hope is, that things have changed in the meantime and solutions have been found. It seems like the phone is switching into some kind of "call mode". I would like to avoid this by either overriding corresponding settings or maybe by using a different way than using web-audio to play the stereo signal. I am open for any ideas. The worst case seems that we have to develop a dedicated native app for ios. If there is any workaround to make this happening in a web app, this would be highly appreciated. If desired, I can provide code snipplets, but I think, at this moment the problem should be clear.

BTW, in android we had similar problems and found that "Dolby Atmos" setting is causing strange mixing down to mono under certain circumstances. Switching it off fixed the android issues. Maybe this helps somebody else and maybe there are global settings on the iphone as well that could cure the problem..

Thank you very much in advance!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

> The worst case seems that we have to develop a dedicated native app for ios.

Unfortunately, this is the path forward most likely to yield success for you (if you haven't already figured this problem out, since I'm answering your question almost a year later).

The audio I/O device landscape is complicated, and there are several standards and factors that play into the quality of audio input and output an application yields. For instance:

- Is the audio input device the same as the audio output device?

  - If yes, is the audio I/O device Bluetooth?

    - If yes, it's unlikely that the Bluetooth audio device supports stereo audio out and simultaneous audio input. Few I/O devices support that, and few host devices support that.
    - If yes, which Bluetooth version does the I/O device support?
- Which operating system is the host device running?
- Does the host device's operating system support the selection of audio input and output devices separately?
- How much access to the host operating system does your application have?

  - For example, if your application is running in a browser, your application will have significantly less control over the host device's operating system's audio subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to work around this problem recently, too. Another developer did a detailed investigation of this using a spectrum analyser and scope, and didn't have any luck either: [testing iOS audio play/record with scope](https://forum.audiob.us/discussion/43320/ios-safari-webaudio-severe-distortion-on-output).

I think building a native app will end up being inevitable, and would also fix the myriad other problems with Safari web audio. Either that or wait until Apple fixes the bugs or implements AudioWorklets.